# Does antenna feed line length affect impedance

Tags: rf, antenna

I built my own antenna but when I measure the impedance (VNA) I see they are off.  One is 30+25J, the other 15 + 10J.  I built these by hand, the only difference I see is the feed line to one is about 1/4 inch loner than the other one.  Of course there could be other differences I don't understand yet.

Comment: An important property of an antenna is the frequency (band) at which one intends to use it. Unfortuantely you omit this crucial information.

Comment: Have you done multiple tests, it could also be the connector affecting readings depending on what kind it is. Also as @Paul said, length matters when reflections come into play.

Comment: Probably your antenna is not matched to the source, therefore the feed line is radiating and acting like additional antenna.

Comment: sorry 2.4Ghz is the frequency

Comment: At those frequencies the effects of a quarter of an inch difference can be enormous. First of all make sure you get rid of any reactance in your antenna, then the length of feedline becomes less important. You'll also make your antenna more efficient if you can get rid of the reactance.

Comment: @captcha should I do that by adding an inductor/capacitor circuit at the antenna itself?  Like with smith chart based matching or should I be tuning the antenna itself (like wire length, gnd size etc.)

Comment: Do you know what your antenna's designed impedance should be? At this stage we don't even know what type of antenna or feedline you're using. It could be misconstructed. Google for a classic article from 1956 called 'My feedline tunes my antenna' by Byron Goodman. This will explain a lot.

Comment: It's just a quater wave monopole, a six inch circle with a 1/4 wave length wire coming out of it.  It's fed with a tiny coax cable.   Ideally that should be 36.5 + j21.25, but that might be with an infinite gnd plane.

Comment: Great article btw, I like how it was published in 1956 but still relevant and easy to follow: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi1xLaJ-v7KAhUKGD4KHQOJCHYQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.rfcec.com%2FRFCEC%2FSection-3%2520-%2520Fundamentals%2520of%2520RF%2520Communication-Electronics%2F27%2520-%2520RF%2520FEEDLINE%2FRF%2520Feedline%2520-%2520My%2520Feedline%2520Tunes%2520My%2520Antenna%2520(By%2520Byron%2520Goodman%2520W1DX%2520QST%2520195603).pdf&usg=AFQjCNFwr1hGfDVPybkO0qMvCvbHdukwuA

Comment: If the coax is 50 ohms you can try using 4 quarter-wave radials as ground plane and drooping them down 45 degrees. This will increase your antenna's impedance closer to 50 ohms, provide a better match with the coax, reduce SWR, make the length of feedline less critical, minimise possible higher voltages at the transmitter and overall increase your radiation efficiency. Pretty much anything can be used as an antenna but doing it right I find much more rewarding. Thanks for the link to the article btw.

Comment: Also, make sure the antennae don't have other conductors inside the near-field.

Comment: I'm voting to close this old question as off-topic because sufficient information to make it answerable has never been provided, and it has started to attract inappropriate response

Answer (score 2):

If your transmission line is exactly 0.5 wavelength, then it will have no effect on impedance.  If it has the same characteristic impedance as the antenna, then it will also have no effect.

However, it's quite difficult to calculate the effect with ≠ 0.5 wavelength (or multiples thereof).

Read this guide: http://www.antennex.com/preview/New/quarter.htm  It should help you a lot.

I would quote it, but the site is huge.  Let me know if you want to put up with an answer that's almost as long as the transcript of the latest Congress session.

Comment: Correction: the feedline lengths where impedances appear the same is at half-wave multiples, not just at full-wave multiples.

Comment: Lovely, great to see people trudging along, updating SE during the small hours.. :-)

Comment: And aren't we glad that we have foolks like you to correct those small-hour mistakes :)

Comment: The power of a compliment isn't just phenomenal; it's I^2 * R

Comment: Looks like the site is down, and this was the last usable version of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20080723122147/http://www.antennex.com/preview/New/quarter.htm

Answer (score 1):

What frequency is this?  The feedline length definitely affects the impedance if you have a load that is not equal to the characteristic impedance of the feedline.   But a 1/4 inch difference won't be measurable until you are way up into the GHz region.